# Unable to get the text of label of the selected select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get the text of label of selected select tag so that I can use that label text and set in another input tag but getting **(an empty string)** ...Following is my HTML code and jquery code

```js
function getClassesAndYear(CollegeId, cnt) {
  var text = $(this).closest('label').text();
  console.log("text");
  console.log(text);
}


//Following is the code used on university select
 function getColleges(UniId, cnt){
   var text = $(UniId).siblings('label').text();
   console.log("text");
   console.log(text);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
This is HTML code-
<div class="col-md-2">
  <label class="control-label">University</label>
  <select name="universityId" class="form-control" onchange="getColleges(this.value, 1)" id="universityNameId1">
    <option value="">Select University</option>
    {% for university in universityName %}
    <option value="{{university.id}}">{{university.university_name}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
  <label class="control-label">College Name</label>
  <select name="collegeName" id="collegeNameId1" onchange="getClassesAndYear(this, 1)" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="">Select College</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
  <label class="control-label">Enrollment Year</label>
  <select name="enrollmentYear" id="yearNameId1" onchange="getClassesAndYear(this, 1)" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="">Select Year</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3">Class</label>
  <select id="classNameId1" class="form-control select2 classNameId" name="className" multiple>
    <option value="">Select Class</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method and use `CollegeId` instead of `this` where `this` is not refers to the element.

```
function getClassesAndYear(CollegeId, cnt){     
    var text = $(CollegeId).siblings('label').text();
    console.log("text");
    console.log(text);
}
```

```js
function getClassesAndYear(CollegeId, cnt) {
  var text = $(CollegeId).siblings('label').text();
  console.log(text);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
This is HTML code-


<div class="col-md-2">
  <label class="control-label">College Name</label>
  <select name="collegeName" id="collegeNameId1" onchange="getClassesAndYear(this, 1)" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="">Select College</option>
    <option value="">Select College</option>
    <option value="">Select College</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
  <label class="control-label">Enrollment Year</label>
  <select name="enrollmentYear" id="yearNameId1" onchange="getClassesAndYear(this, 1)" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="">Select Year</option>
    <option value="">Select Year</option>
    <option value="">Select Year</option>
    <option value="">Select Year</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3">Class</label>
  <select id="classNameId1" class="form-control select2 classNameId" name="className" multiple>
    <option value="">Select Class</option>
    <option value="">Select Class</option>
    <option value="">Select Class</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I am getting the text of labels of college,class and enrollment-year but not in case of university..I have updated the javascript code above..Please check

Comment: @Rupali :  instead of passing `this.value` pass `this` as argument

Comment: @Pranav-I have done this-var text=$(this).siblings('label').text();    but still giving  (an empty string)

Comment: @Rupali :  I mean `onchange="getColleges(this.value, 1)"` ===> `onchange="getColleges(this, 1)"`